# Array is present, but not recognize

Tags: python, arrays, json, for-loop

I have an array that is occasionally empty or none existence. I continuously get an error message saying it doesn't exist, but clearly, does. Here is the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ab67322\Desktop\python\Weather\weatheropen1.1.py", line 23, in 
    rain = n['rain']
KeyError: 'rain'

Any help is much appreciated.

```
NMNorthzip=[87401,87301]

for x in NMNorthzip:

    r = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip="+str(x)+",us&appid=id")

    data = r.json()
    forecast = data['list']
    pprint(forecast)


    for n in forecast:
        if n['rain'] is None:
            print ("empty")
        else:
            print(n['rain'])
```

Output>>>

```
 {'clouds': {'all': 92},
  'dt': 1494093600,
   'dt_txt': '2017-05-06 18:00:00',
   'main': {'grnd_level': 822.44,
       'humidity': 62,
       'pressure': 822.44,
       'sea_level': 1018.05,
       'temp': 292.882,
       'temp_kf': 0,
       'temp_max': 292.882,
       'temp_min': 292.882},
  'rain': {'3h': 0.125},
  'sys': {'pod': 'd'},
  'weather': [{'description': 'light rain',
           'icon': '10d',
           'id': 500,
           'main': 'Rain'}],
   'wind': {'deg': 143.002, 'speed': 3.11}}]
```

Comment: What array's absence raises the exception? And can you put the exception message into your question so that we understand the problem?

Comment: n['rain'] is the error. I will update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check, whether key `rain` exists

```
for n in forecast:
   if 'rain' in n:
       print(n['rain'])
   else:
       print('empty')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Np dude;) We just changed a little logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that your call to `requests..get()` is successful. You could have a network problem, DNS failure, the server be down or refuse the connection...

You can check the response status code:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Requests also comes with a built-in status code lookup object for easy reference:

```
>>> r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
True
```

If you made a bad request (a 4XX client error or 5XX server error response), you can raise it with Response.raise_for_status():

```
>>> bad_r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/404')
>>> bad_r.status_code
404

>>> bad_r.raise_for_status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/models.py", line 832, in raise_for_status
    raise http_error
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error
```

Comment: It is not a bad request I have tested it as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`forecast` is a dictionary, and a dictionary has keys. You have the statement `for n in forecast:` which will assign each of the keys in this dictionary to `n` one at a time. At some point, `n` will be set to `rain` which is **not** subscriptable (it's neither a list nor a dictionary).

If you want to know about rain then simply leave out that `for` statement.